# C Non-Blocking UDP Socket

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have been looking around with no avail on how to make the client receive requests from server without blocking the main loop, I apologize if there's a duplicate out there, but all I've been finding online are TCP versions, which don't work for my purpose (UDP).

Right now the server is just an Echo Server so I don't really care if it blocks.

The server is created as follows

```
ServerInstance Init(ServerConfiguration c) {
  ServerInstance n;
  n.endpoint = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  Exitif(n.endpoint < 0, "Error opening endpoint socket");
  setsockopt(n.endpoint, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void *) &c.trueval, sizeof(int));
  setzero((char *) &n.servaddr, sizeof(n.servaddr));
  n.servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  n.servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  n.servaddr.sin_port = htons(c.portno);
  Exitif(bind(n.endpoint, (struct sockaddr *) &n.servaddr, sizeof(n.servaddr)) < 0,
  "Error on binding socket to addr");
  n.buf = calloc(c.buffersize, sizeof(char))
  return n;
}
```

As for the client:

```
  connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  IfThenExit(socket < 0, "Error initializing UDP socket\n");
  setzero((char *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  IfThenExit(inet_aton(SRVADDR, &servaddr.sin_addr) == 0, "IPV4 Address Invalid\n");
  CleanQueueAdd(&connection, Socket);
```

And it loops as the above, I also have SDL's event pool, and I'd like to know how I can implement something like that without blocking the program

```
if(1) {
  while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
    switch(e.type) {
      case SDL_QUIT:
        quit = 1;
        break;
      case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        quit = 1;
        break;
    }
  }
  // Recv here blocks ...
  // recv(...)
}
```

Thank you for reading and have a nice day

Comment: What protocol the network connection the socket references is using has no effect on how you set a socket non-blocking and use it. The socket interface is network protocol independent.

Comment: You have two options. I expect to see code which 1/ sets the socket mode to non-blocking, or 2/ calls socket functions using options to specify non-blocking calls... yet I see none of these two... and so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Seb I set the socket to non-blocking mode after I put this question, but is that optimal compared to poll or select? I read it wasted CPU cycles

Comment: @Whiteclaws 1/ [What is premature optimisation?](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) 2/ No. The calls to `recv` are necessary, anyway, aren't they? You end up calling them anyway, don't you? Once you've looped through, calling `recv` for each of your *non-blocking* sockets, use `sleep(0)` to force a context switch, giving the OS a chance to put more data in the queues and... no waste ;) Furthermore, `poll` and `select` *aren't exclusively* non-blocking, and *you haven't shown us that code*! **There's nothing *non-blocking* in this question!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that SDL events cannot be multiplexed with arbitrary non-SDL events.  Instead, you can create a secondary thread which uses `select()` or `epoll()` or some wrapper around those.  This thread will wait for network messages, read and perhaps parse them, and pass the requests to the main thread using `SDL_PushEvent`.

Comment: Nah, I don't want to push events to the SDL queue, but rather find a way to poll events in a non-blocking way - just like SDL does with SDL_PollEvent, Are there any examples around the net on how to implement that with poll or select? No Multi-threading if possible, basically, I want to call recv and return immediately if there's no packets that are waiting to be read

Comment: @Whiteclaws: You can find thousands of examples of how to do IO multiplexing using select() on sockets, but then how are you going to check for SDL events?  If you really need to check for SDL events and also for socket events, you may actually need to do active polling or busy-waiting: check the socket for data, check the SDL queue for events, sleep a while, and repeat.  This process will be inefficient but will allow the use of a single thread.

Comment: Neither `select` nor `epoll` are exclusively non-blocking; according to [the manual for the former](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/select.html), *"... `select()` blocks, up to the specified timeout interval, until the specified condition is true for at least one of the specified file descriptors"*, and the latter is *asynchronous I/O* (which is different to non-blocking I/O).